# Move along bendy bones

Tags: rigging, bones

I have a belt prepared for animation, using bendy bones

[image]

I need this stuff(screenshot below) move along bendy bones

[image]

How can I do this? (I need exactly bendy bones and not any curves, because it is easier to animate for my purposes)
Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Using Spline IK for your belt and use the curve to follow path would make things easy but why don't you want a curve?

Comment: For animations I need it is more comfort to use exactly bendy bones, I need more control on belt shape, it is going to interact with hands so I need high accuracy and with bendy bones I can control almost any part of the belt. By my experience curves behavior  is more unpredictable then bendy bones

Comment: why more unpredictable? You can parent each vertex of your curve to a bone and make it very controllable... it also depends on your purpose I guess, what kind of animation, etc

Comment: if I parent each vertex of my the curve to a bone the shape of the curve doesn't much to my bendy bones shape, here is screenshot
https://ibb.co/k9jkTwG

Comment: also there is impossible rotate around curve, but I can do it with bendy bones, so it is also what I need during animation and that because can't use curve
here is screenshot
https://ibb.co/Kz1rqbz

Comment: I was talking about getting rid of your bendy bone and using a curve that you can control with some bones, or curve + armature with spline IK + bones to control the curve... actually it also depends on what you want to be able to do with your belt, what is your storyboard etc...

Comment: Okay, thanks! I have understood that I can't do this only with bendy bones. With the curves I know how to move along it. Thanks!